# Error while restarting the build using checkpoints in pipeline plugin of jenkins

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I want to restart using checkpoints in `jenkins-pipeline-plugin`.

I installed `workflow-cps-checkpoint.hpi` plugin.

This is my groovy script:

```
checkpoint 'task1'
stage 'task1'

node('agent'){
  echo 'executing task1'
  sleep 20
}

checkpoint 'task2'
stage 'task2'

node('agent'){
  echo 'executing task2'
  sleep 20
}
```

I got the below error when I ran the build:

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No such DSL method 'checkpoint' found among steps [archive, bat, build, catchError, checkout, deleteDir, dir, echo, error,
fileExists, input, isUnix, libraryResource, load, mail, milestone, node, parallel, properties, pwd, readFile, readTrusted, retry, sh, sleep, stage,
stash, step, timeout, tool, unarchive, unstash, waitUntil, withEnv, wrap, writeFile, ws] or symbols [all, always, ant, antFromApache, antOutcome,
antTarget, apiToken, architecture, archiveArtifacts, artifactManager, batchFile, booleanParam, buildButton, buildDiscarder, caseInsensitive,
caseSensitive, choice, choiceParam, clock, cloud, command, cron, crumb, defaultView, demand, disableConcurrentBuilds, downloadSettings, downstream,
dumb, envVars, file, fileParam, filePath, fingerprint, frameOptions, freeStyle, freeStyleJob, git, hyperlink, hyperlinkToModels, installSource,
jdk, jdkInstaller, jgit, jnlp, jobName, junit, lastDuration, lastFailure, lastGrantedAuthorities, lastStable, lastSuccess, legacy, list, local, 
location, logRotator, loggedInUsersCanDoAnything, masterBuild, maven, maven3Mojos, mavenErrors, mavenMojos, mavenWarnings, myView, nodeProperties,
nonStoredPasswordParam, none, overrideIndexTriggers, paneStatus, parameters, password, pattern, pipelineTriggers, plainText, plugin, 
projectNamingStrategy, proxy, queueItemAuthenticator, quietPeriod, run, runParam, schedule, scm, scmRetryCount, search, security, shell, slave,
stackTrace, standard, status, string, stringParam, swapSpace, text, textParam, tmpSpace, toolLocation, unsecured, upstream, viewsTabBar, weather, 
zfs, zip] or globals [currentBuild, env, params, scm]

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.DSL.invokeMethod(DSL.java:149)

at org.jenkinsci.plugins.workflow.cps.CpsScript.invokeMethod(CpsScript.java:108)
```

Answer (score 2):

The error message you show indicates that no plugin is installed that provides the `checkpoint` keyword.

The `workflow-cps-checkpoint` plugin isn't part of open source Jenkins; it's a closed-source feature provided by the company [CloudBees](https://release-notes.cloudbees.com/product/CloudBees+Pipeline%3A+Groovy+Checkpoint+Plugin).  If you're a customer of theirs, you should contact their support.

However, CloudBees have said that they [plan to open-source the plugin](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846?focusedCommentId=297346&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-297346) at some point.

Comment: I am not an enterprise customer of jenkins, i am using there open source version. Is there any other plugin available to restart a build for a certain checkpoints???

Comment: Jenkins itself doesn't provide enterprise versions; other companies do that. I don't know of any other checkpoint implementations. You would likely have to split your pipeline into multiple jobs if you want to (re)start builds from different points.

Comment: Currently this is still not possible in OSS version but voting is going on at their issue tracker [JENKINS-33846](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-33846)